# Single-Step Return Statement or Multi-Step Return Statement

Tags: c++, coding-style

Example 1:

```
int length()  
{  
        return strlen(random_string);  
}
```

Example 2:

```
int length()  
{  
        int str_length = 0;  
        str_length = strlen(random_string);  
        return str_length;  
}
```

Question:
I have come across many functions where a single line of code could satisfy the requisite for that function, but I recall something about avoiding this kind of shortcut.

Are there certain situations where one is more appropriate than another or should I always go for the simpler piece of code.

Comment: To a decent compiler, that should not make any difference. Choose whatever comes more readable or maintainable to you.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Yet, NRVO....

Comment: It's better to do multi-line statements if the function performs multiple operations, and the possibility of the implementation changing is not zero.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Wouldn't the compiler elide the copy in any case?

Comment: @AndyProwl: Maybe, if it can still do RVO.

Comment: BTW your eight-space indentation has hurt my eyes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I thought when back NRVO was a new fancy compiler feature, most of them could *already* do RVO on a temporary.  Before that point, the shorter version was better, and afterward it didn't matter.

Comment: @aschepler: Yeah, more or less. I just wanted to jump on "that should not make any difference". It makes a difference _to_ the compiler, even if the end [read: compiled] result is likely to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason to have a a multi-step approach is that if you ever decide to add a line to print the value of length, it's a lot less hassle:

```
int length()
{
    const int str_length = strlen(something);
    printf("str_length = %d\n", str_length);
    return str_length;
}
```

Or if you want to add some extra assert:

```
int length()
{
    const int str_length = strlen(something);
    assert(str_length >= 0);
    return str_length;
}
```

Other than that, it's all about what you feel is most appropriate [unless you have strict coding standards to follow, of course!]

Comment: You forgot the `const`!

Answer (score 2):

I would never go for your second example, because the initialisation-then-assignment is just taking up space for no reason.

What I *might* do is the following:

```
int length()  
{  
    const int str_length = strlen(arbitrary_string);  
    return str_length;  
}
```

This is for two reasons:

1. You allow your compiler to perform the Named Return-Value Optimisation; and
2. Your return value is now self-documenting by virtue of having a name.

However, that's more of a *default* rule for me.

In this specific, actual case:

1. Your return type is only a measly little `int`, so the Named Return-Value Optimisation isn't permitted anyway, and would be largely pointless even if it were; and
2. The function is already trivial and appropriately-named.

So I'd be using the first example:

```
int length()  
{  
    return strlen(arbitrary_string);
}
```

Comment: One other advantage: It can make debugging easier when you can see what value the code is producing before you return it.

Comment: Would example 2 actually prevent NRVO? "in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing
the automatic object directly into the function's return value"

Comment: @Lightness is your 2nd code is more optimized then 1st one or both are same. ?

Comment: @sftrabbit: Well, the expression isn't a name, so yes :)

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Very true

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I meant example 2 from the question!

Comment: @sftrabbit: Oh, right. So what are you focusing on, the fact that the return type is non-class?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe I'm just misinterpreting your answer, but it sounds like you're saying your first example is better than the asker's "Example 2" because it allows NRVO, but I thought both of them would allow it. But now you've just pointed out that it has to be class return type, so now I think both of them *disallow* it!

Comment: @sftrabbit: You're right. My first list is about arbitrary `T`, and the second is about why those points are largely moot in the _specific_ examples that the OP provides. But I didn't do a brilliant job of showing that.

Answer (score 1):

I say always go with example 1. It reads much more nicely. I would only ever not put the expression in the return statement if the intermediate variable name aided readability or if the expression ought to be split into multiple statements.

I would never suggestion example 2, though - the initialisation to 0 is pointless. The middle ground is better:

```
int length()  
{  
    int str_length = strlen(random_string);  
    return str_length;  
}
```

However, it's clear that `str_length` doesn't tell you any more than the function name `strlen` does.

Answer (score 0):

In general code should be easy to read and make the purpose clear. In your example I would prefer the shorter version. There is no additional information gain about the semantics with the long version.

As always there may be exceptions. Especially when the returned value arises from a long and complicted expression. Then it might be helpful to name some of the intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question always choose the easier to read solution, this is important in every programming language but it's extremely important in C++.

For your particular question the easiest to read for a C++ developer is the option number 1, it is clean and simple. BUT if it happens that the single line you have to write is like:

```
return (classA *)(function1(data1)->function2())->function3();
```

In this cases allways choose to split the line, because even if you understand what it does right now, you can have a hard time to figure out what's happening in there in the future.

Hope it helps

Comment: That bad example is also terrible to debug, mostly because debuggers tend to "think" in lines (mostly), e.g. I haven't seen a debugger where you can put a breakpoint somewhere in the middle of a line.

Answer (score -1):

In most cases, readability always trumps performance. If you are having performance-critical code, then go for performance. However, that is an exception, rather than the rule.

Always go for readability.

Comment: Always go for readability yes, but this present example the first one have actually a better readability. Of course I'll not return 300 characters line to win some space.